# Pass data between gulp tasks without writing to disk

Tags: angularjs, gulp, systemjs, ng-annotate

I'm trying to annotate and minify a systemjs angular project. Systemjs comes with a build function, but it is not `'gulp-aware'. There is the possibility to pass the builder an option to minify, but there is not one for ng-annotate, so I will need gulp to do both for me instead.

```
gulp.task('bundle', function () {
    var options = {}
    builder.buildStatic('./assets/app/app.js', options)
    .then(function(data) {
        console.log("then called");
        // make data available for another task            
    });
```

How can I combine the above with

```
gulp.task('productionApp', function() {
    return [source the output from 'bundle']
    .pipe(ngannotate())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist'));
});
```

I could just output the first task to a file, and then `.src` that in, but that can't be the best way?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to save it inside a buffer (actually, a simple object), then make a stream of and continue as you would with `src`.

Gulp's repository contains a [recipe](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/recipes/make-stream-from-buffer.md) how it's done.

*Note:* you should make all those `load-*` tasks to run at the very beginning, you can either use `run-sequence` as they've done or make them as dependencies of the "real" tasks.

Comment: Yikes - this is really complicated. Makes me think I am looking at the problem the wrong way somehow?

Comment: Why complicated? pretty straight forward and elegant. You can always save it inside an intermediate directory as you suggested, but it could be slower. In addition, you can build an abstraction on-top of it to get things easier. Anyway, this way you can "communicate" (data) between tasks without save the actual data in fs.

Comment: OK, I may try again, but now I see that ng-annotate + systemjs is also a bit fiddly. Life on the bleeding edge...

Answer (score 0):

The [yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs) package on npm exports the object `argv`, wich is a very clever representation of the command-line params. For example, the invocation

```
gulp -a test -b 123 my-task
```

is represented during the run by a param `argv` with value

```
{ a: 'test', b: 123 }
```

which is passed to the gulp task `my-task` and, before it, to all its predecessors.

If one of the predecessors assigns a new prop to `argv`

```
argv.newProp = 'newValue'
```

this prop will be available to all its successors, including the task that you really want to execute.

The instruction `const { argv } = require('yargs')` is to be put at the start of the gulpfile, and it can be enriched with aliases and defaults. Reference is [here](https://github.com/yargs/yargs/blob/HEAD/docs/api.md#api)